# Why is Convert.ToDouble(char) not supported?

Tags: c#

From the msdn page :

> `public static double ToDouble(
>     char value
>   )`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *value*
>   Type: System.Char
>   The Unicode character to convert.
>
> *Return Value*
>   Type: System.Double
>   This conversion is not supported. No value is returned.

If it is not supported, why is it implemented in the first place ?

Comment: Probably because it had to be, for some interface, IConvertible, maybe? Or just to keep a standard. Don't let it be missing and looked for - but say "here it is, don't use it though"

Comment: @YoryeNathan `Convert` is a static class, it doesn't implement any interfaces. `Char` does implement `IConvertible`, and *its* `ToDouble` is required for that, but `Convert` doesn't need it. Your alternative, "to keep a standard", may be right.

Comment: @hvd You're right. That was foolish of me.

Comment: You may add to the question that something like `Convert.ToDouble('A'-'0')` works ! !

Comment: @V4Vendetta var x2 = 'A'-'0';
x2.GetType().Name

Comment: @V4Vendetta - That is because char+char=int in C# just like short+short=int. So it would end up calling `Convert.ToDouble(int)` instead of `Convert.ToDouble(char)`

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen oops, yes you are right

Comment: @AdrianIftode Those lines got me, i assumed something else thanks

Comment: @V4Vendetta - I was quite suprised the time I found that out as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the only one.  Convert.ToBoolean(char), ToDateTime, ToDecimal and ToSingle are also not supported, they all throw InvalidCastException like ToDouble does.

This is just .NET design trying to keep you out of trouble.  Converting a char to an integral type is reasonable, you can look at the Unicode mapping tables and count the codepoints.  But what would a conversion to Boolean mean?  What Unicode code point is True?  ToDateTime requires no explanation.  How could a character ever be a *fractional* value?  There are no half or quarter codepoints.

You *can* make it work, convert to Int32 first and then convert to Double.  But by all means, check your code and make sure that it is a *senseful* thing to do.  The .NET designers thought it wasn't.  They were right.

Comment: It make sense. However `double doubleChar = (double) 'a'; //OK` and `var doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble('a'); //InvalidCastException` is a bit inconsistent.

Comment: Hehe, the designers just didn't have power to make that throw.  Language rules trump framework design.

Answer (score 3):

As per MSDN, this function is keep reserved for future use in .Net 2.0 and it's kept till 4.5 for supporting previous version of .net frameworks.

They will implement this if future OS will support this type of conversion. Currently, OS stores the char as int, so not providing the way to cast char to double due to lots of inner conversions.

Due to internal storage format, same limitation is with  Convert.ToDouble(DateTime).

Answer (score 2):

Each character has a corresponding integer. For example:

```
Convert.ToInt16('a') -> returns 97.
```

I guess the main reason why the Convert doesn't support to convert from a char the other types  is that the second nature of a character is the integer type.

Maybe a more clear example is the following code:

```
char a = 'a';
int aVal = (int)a;
```

Which actually Convert.ToInt32 does ( but also raises the overflow exception)

Answer (score 1):

[A char can be implicitly converted to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9h8tsay.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, given that `Convert` has a lot of conversion methods between types that have implicit conversions to each other.

Comment: @Joey It actually does answer the question. Without a `Convert.ToDouble(char)` overload to throw an exception, another overload that doesn't throw an exception would be picked, and `Convert.ToDouble(char)` would no longer behave the same as `((IConvertible)char).ToDouble()`.